# Is the defined set dense in $R$ (if true)?

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that the given set is dense in $R$ (if true)? 
**SET:** The set of all ration numbers ${p \over q}$ with $10|p| \ge q$ where $p \in \Bbb Z, q \in \Bbb N$.

As per definition, a set is considered dense in $\Bbb R$ if an element of the set can be found between any two real numbers ($a<b$), how to use the given defnition or Arcimedean Property to solve the problem?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{|p|}q\ge \frac1{10}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, So there can be no element of set that can be found for $x < 1/10 $ in $R$. Hence not dense in $R$. Correct ?